# Sigma.js Search for Nodes

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I am a total beginner to javascript but hope to accomplish certain tasks with it regarding Sigma.js

Firstly I would like to know how to search nodes. From what I have gathered online. If I make a form the following javascript will read it:

```
  function readText (form) {
    TestVar =form.inputbox.value;
    alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);

//Here I am trying to loop through all the nodes to see if it matches the typed value.
    sigma.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
            if(n.id==TestVar)
          n.color = "#fff";
      });

    }
```

Doing it this way does not work. I realize that I do have to bind it or something of the sort. By looking through the .js file given I cannot find any keyboard listeners.

```
s.bind('??', function(??) {
    //Get Value

    // Loop through nodes to get value.
});
```

I realize that I must do something like that but hours of searching I cannot find out how. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sigma.js' role is to deal with the graph.

You should handle the keyboard events with vanilla javascript, or with a library like jQuery.

Try to assign an Id to your text input, and then do something like :

```
var searchBox = document.getElementById("textInputId")

searchBox.addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
  readText(evt.target)
})
```

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener for more information.